# Word decomposition algorithm

Tags: algorithm, dictionary, hash

Let A be a finite alphabet and A* the set of all the finite strigns you can form from that alphabet. You are then given a set F of some strings from A* (tipically a lot smaller than A*) that contains the alphabet itself (A), and a string S beloging to A*.

Is there a polynomial time algorithm to find the minimum decomposition of S in terms of strings that belong to F?

By decomposition I mean a writing of S = F<sub>1</sub>...F<sub>k</sub> of concatenated strings F<sub>j</sub> that belong to F, and you are trying to minimize the number k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can solve this in polynomial time using dynamic programming as follows.

Let D[i] be the minimum decomposition of the first i letters i of your string S.

If n is the length of S, and f is the total length of all strings in F, we can compute D in time O(n.f) by iterating over i.

For each value of i we try all choices in F for the end of the string and pick the one that results in the minimum decomposition.

Once we have done this, the answer to the original question is contained in D[n].

### Python code

```
F=['abcd','de','a','b','c','d']
S='abcde'

D = [ [] ]
for i in range(1,len(S)+1):
    s = S[:i]
    best = None
    for f in F:
        if s.endswith(f):
            a = D[i-len(f)]
            if a is None:
                continue
            if best is None or len(a) < len(best):
                best = a + [f]
    D.append(best)

print D[len(S)]
```

prints:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'de']
```